# Opening files in Mac using python

Tags: python

I am sort of new to python. I can open files in Windows with but am having trouble in Mac. I can open webbrowsers but I am unsure as to how I open other programs or word documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this code:
f = open("A.txt")
for line in f:
    print line
f.close()

the file is located within the same directory of program files.

is there error message?

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, the launcher to open any document, URL, etc. is `open`.

To invoke it from Python, try this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['open', mypath])
```

On Linux and other *nix systems, use `xdg-open`.